# Does A transpose = - A transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

The question I am currently struggling with is

Does there exist an $\ n×n $ real matrix$\ A $ such that

$\ tr(A)= \ 0 $ and $\ A^2+A^T=\ I $?

For some reason, the solution starts with

$\ I= \ A^2−A^T $

instead of $\ I = \ A^2 + A^T $ as stated in the problem.

which leads me to think that $\ A^T =\ -A^T $

Is this true?

The solution I am looking at is this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Q9D.png

Comment: Since the solution states the matrix cannot exist, the question whether this non-existing matrix satisfies $A^T = - A^T$ is somewhat weird...

Comment: I expect that there was a typo in the question and they intended $I = A^2 - A^T$

Comment: Something else: the only matrix satisfying $-X = X$ is the null-matrix, so if $A^T = -A^T$ then $A^T= 0$ and hence $A = 0$. But then we check that $A^2 + A^T = 0$ and not $I$. In other words, from the conditions in the question it follows that $A^T$ is NOT equal to $-A^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no, that is a mistake from the solution makers. However, if you use $I=A^2+A^\top$ where they write $I=A^2-A^\top$, the argument doesn't change that much.

**Edit**: if the question makers intended to write $I=A^2 - A^\top$, then note that for any solution $A$, we could define $B=-A$ and we would get $I=B^2 + B^\top$. The other way around works as well. Thus, it doesn't matter what the exact sign is, the problems are equivalent, and the argument is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !